# Help with batch file to start Powershell in specific directory & retain settings

Tags: batch, powershell

I'm running Win7 and have Powershell docked on my taskbar.  When I launch it from there, it retains all of my color and font settings from the last time I used it.  I have two questions.  First, if I try to run PS from a batch script just by using:

```
powershell
```

it will launch with all of the system default settings (white on black, tiny text).

Second, what do I need to add to the command to launch PS and have it start in a specific directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can view the current console properties with `(Get-Host).UI.RawUI`

To change them you can cut and paste this, for example:

```
$a = (Get-Host).UI.RawUI
$a.BackgroundColor = "white"
$a.ForegroundColor = "black"
Set-Location C:\foo
Clear-Host
```

(You can actually copy the above script and paste it in directly, where it will execute line-by-line, which is a pretty cool thing about PowerShell)

If you save it to...

`%USERPROFILE%\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1`

`$home\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1`

...it will execute every time you start PowerShell in that user account.